# Hover to multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to apply a `hover` for a whole block (the same block must point to a link), but can't make this happen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GogjQK

I've tried to wrap an `<a>` tag around the entire frame class and edit the hover states individually, but nothing happens.

This is how I'm trying to make it appear on hover, as well when the the link is clicked and active

[image]

Hope someone can help me out with this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't see any `:hover` pseudo-class in your code..

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use child selectors on your `frame` div to affect the children within.

For example, I added the following code to color the `h3` tag when the main frame is hovers.

```
.frame:hover > div > h3 {
  color: #00bb00;
}
```

If you modify your HTML slightly to be

```
<div class="frame">
  <img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/903/WUtWQJ.png" class="thumbnail" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" class="thumbnail" id="hidden" />
  <div class="info">
    <h3>H3</h3>
    <p>pppppp</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use the following CSS to change the image as well:

```
.frame:hover > .thumbnail {
  display:none;
}

.frame:hover > #hidden {
  display:inline;
}

#hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Here's an example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bENBGW).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hyper reference after the creation of the div that contains your block, like this:

```
<div class="frame"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
  <img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/903/WUtWQJ.png"
class="thumbnail" />
  <div class="info">
    <h3>H3</h3>
    <p>pppppp</p>
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then in CSS, refer to the entire block as a link, like this:

```
.frame a {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: ##00F;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.frame a:hover > .info > h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

Example:  [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKYbgV)